# How do I make modprobe permanent?

Tags: drivers, modprobe

For my wireless adapter (inside my computer) to enable it, I run `modprobe b43` and that turns it on. But, when I reboot it goes back to no device. So, how do I make this totally permanent?

Answer (score 23):

Add b43 to /etc/modules file. It should work (You can add it by running the following command)

```
echo b43 | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

Comment: That's not ubuntu-like, a sudo of this will give "permission denied". Use `sudoedit /etc/modules`

Comment: Alternative sudo version: `echo "b43" | sudo tee -a /etc/modules`